# Convergent sequence of a special topology on $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, integers

Can we characterize all the convergent sequences of the topology on $\mathbb{Z}$ (Furstenberg's topology) generated by the basic open sets of the form $B(c,r)=\{c+rk \mid k\in \mathbb{Z} \}$, for $c,r\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $r>0$?

The question is linked to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4240218/limit-in-a-topology), where we try to find the limit of a specific sequence.

Comment: In the definition of $B(c,r)$ must be $k\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: thank you for pointing out